# How to select a container in Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm trying to display a "list" of containers: I mean I created a container ( I'll call it container A ) to display data:

ID docked on the left of the container, name on top, task name ( for example ) at bottom and date docked on the right.

Next I try to display this containers in another container ( container B): some containers inside a bigger container so I can display the data.

But I need to select a container A if I want to delete or edit it. How can I do it?

Thank you very much.

Edit:

Code: "container A" (.../app/view/Cliente.js)

```
Ext.define('proyecto.view.Cliente', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',        
xtype: 'cliente',
requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],

config: {
title: 'Cliente',
iconCls: 'info',
xtype: 'container',
layout: 'vbox',
margin: 10,
padding: 5, border: 15,
    items: [
    {
        docked: 'left',
        xtype: 'container',
        width: 100,
        html: 'ID_cliente',
        style: 'background-color: #00CED1'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        flex: 2,
        html: 'Nombre',
        style: 'background-color: #6495ED'  
    },
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        flex: 1,
        html: '<DIV ALIGN=right><span style="background-color:#4169E1">Asignaciones</span></DIV>',
    },
    ]
}});
```

Code: "container B" (.../app/view/ListaClientes.js)

```
Ext.define('proyecto.view.ListaClientes', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',

xtype: 'listaclientes',
requires: ['Ext.TitleBar', 'proyecto.view.Cliente'],
config: {
title: 'Lista de Clientes',
iconCls: 'team',
scrollable: true,
    items: [
{   
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    title: 'Lista de clientes',
    docked: 'top',
    items:  [
    {
        text: 'Nuevo'/*,
        action: 'nuevocliente'*/
    },
    {
        text: 'Editar'/*,
        action: 'editarcliente',
        enableOnSelection: true,
        disabled: true */
    },
    {
        xtype: 'spacer'
    },
    {
        text: 'Eliminar'/*,
        action: 'eliminarcliente',
        enableOnSelection: true,
        disabled: true */
    }
    ]
},
{       //example visualization
    xtype: 'cliente',
    height: 80,
}, 
{
    xtype: 'cliente',
    height: 80,
}, 
{
    xtype: 'cliente',
    height: 80,
}, 
{
    xtype: 'cliente',
    height: 80,
}                   
]
}});
```

Screen Container B: I can't upload the screen here, I'm newbie :(
http://s7.postimg.org/q0gppq8h7/Container_B.jpg

Comment: It would be better if you could include a screenshot or a link to it or some code.

Comment: Hello. I included Code of both containers and a picture of the "list". I need to select in this list in order to edit or delete the container selected, I hope that is clear. English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the container you mentioned is not a generic container in HTML form concept but a real class in sencha touch.

I would recommend you to have a look how to use the component query in sencha touch framework, as that is the most powerful and basic search utility in the framework. if you organise your object properly, it can get anything for you easily. if you from css & jquery selector background, you feel you were home when checking how to use

have a look here:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

if you also interested with the jquery type of search which is at the dom level, here is a good example.

http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/element.html

also, some similar feature offered in:

docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp

I use the 2.3 as an example, but these features exist since earlier release. Hopefully these can help.